# How can i write HttpStreamContent to file?

Tags: c#, file, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, http-streaming

this is my code for downloading a file.
but im not sure how to write the file to disk.

```
private async Task DownloadFile()
{
    HttpStreamContent streamContent = new HttpStreamContent(new SlowInputStream(streamLength));
    IProgress<HttpProgress> progress = new Progress<HttpProgress>(ShowProgress);
    response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), streamContent).AsTask(cts.Token, progress);
}
```

im not sure what to write here and where to call WriteToFile():

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
{
    var myFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(filename.Replace("---", " - ")+".mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
    ///stuck here
}
```

Comment: You need to write response to the file? Please clarify

Comment: What does response contains? File content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working this way:

```
private async Task DownloadFile()
    {

        IProgress<HttpProgress> progress = new Progress<HttpProgress>(ShowProgress);
        try
        {

            response = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(downloadUrl), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).AsTask(cts.Token, progress);
            DownloadMessageText.Text = "Download complete. Writing to disk...";
            await WriteToFile();
            DownloadMessageText.Text = "File saved in music library.";
        }
        catch { }


    }
```

and writing to disk:

```
private async Task WriteToFile()
    {
        var myFile = await KnownFolders.MusicLibrary.CreateFileAsync(filename.Replace("---", " - ") + ".mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        var fs = await myFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
        IBuffer buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
        await fs.WriteAsync(buffer);
    }
```